# Are these hangars?

Tags: airport-design, hangar

I found an AFB in Germany that has some sort of hangars. Look:
[image: germanAfb]

And here there are more but in other AFB:
[image: germanafb2]

Are they hangars? If so, why are they covered with grass?

Comment: old WWII camouflage maybe?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardened_aircraft_shelter, [here's an image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hardened+aircraft+shelter&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWlKfX4IHLAhUFthoKHShECQ8Q_AUIBygB&biw=1344&bih=740#imgrc=0VMujnc0H1mWsM%3A)

Comment: [Another question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21148/8730) about dispersal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are hardened aircraft shelters (HAS) designed to protect aircraft from air attack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardened_aircraft_shelter

In the first picture, they are also on a "dispersal" to spread them out and make them harder to target.

Comment: Dispersal is less about making aircraft or other ground assets harder to target and more about reducing the amount of damage that can be done by any single bomb. It turns one big target (a tight group of parked aircraft) into lots of small targets.